# Google Sheets compare column to same column on all sheets

Tags: javascript, google-sheets, compare

```
    function setStrikeThru(range) {
      var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet;
      var sheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSheet();
      var cell = sheet.getRange(range);
      cell.setFontLine("line-through");
    }
    //
    function compareTwo() {
    // strike through duplicates on user pages
    //if on here
      var sheetNameToWatch1 = "WEEKLY COMPLETED JOBS";
    //or here
      var sheetNameToWatch2 = "PAST JOBS";
    //strikethrough here
      var shtNames = ["0","Adia","Alejandra","Austin","Daniel","David L"];
    //loop through number of values in array
      for(var j=1; j < shtNames.length; j++){
        var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
    //use this sheet as values to check for
        var sheet = ss.getSheetByName(sheetNameToWatch1);
    //strike through on this sheet
        var targetSheet = ss.getSheetByName(shtNames);
    //count number of rows to check
        var totalRows = sheet.getRange(targetSheet.getLastRow() + 1, 1);
   //loop through number of rows
        for (var i = 1; i < totalRows; i++){
          var cell = "C" + i;
          var valToChk = sheet.getRange(cell) ;
          if (sheet.getRange(cell)===targetSheet.getRange(cell) ){
            setStrikeThru(targetSheet.getRange(cell));
          }
        }
      }
```

I have no idea if I'm close on this.

basically i have a main sheet "Weekly completed jobs" I want to compare the values on this sheet column C to the column C on all the other sheets and strike through on the the other sheets if it exists on "Weekly Completed Jobs"

I've been successful writing other codes to copy rows and move them based on values but i cant get the logic right on this one. Javascript is not my native language. Thanks for the help in advanced.

Answer (score 1):

You are comparing range objects, this will not work. You need to extract the values from the range and compare the values, using [range#getValues()](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/spreadsheet/range#getvalues). Below is an example that might help you.

```
function compare() {
  var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
  var controlSheet = ss.getSheetByName("WEEKLY COMPLETED JOBS");
  var column = 3;
  var firstValueRow = 2;
  var lastRow = controlSheet.getLastRow();
  var controlValues = controlSheet.getRange(firstValueRow, column, lastRow).getValues();
  var sheetsToCheck = ["Adia", "Alejandra", "Daniel", "David L"];
  sheetsToCheck.forEach(function (sheetName) {
    var sheetToCheck = ss.getSheetByName(sheetName);
    if (!sheetToCheck) {
      throw new Error("No sheet with name: " + sheetName);
    }
    var checkValues = sheetToCheck.getRange(firstValueRow, column, lastRow).getValues();
    for (var i = 0; i < controlValues.length; i++) {
      controlValue = controlValues[i][0];
      if (controlValue) {
        var checkValue = checkValues[i][0];
        if (controlValue === checkValue) {
          sheetToCheck.getRange(i + firstValueRow, column).setFontLine("line-through");
        }
      }
    }
  });
}
```

Comment: thank you rckrd. This project got put on hold  at work I really appreciate the help and direction. I'll let you know how it goes!